# Read Javascript variable from .NET in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor

I am new to Blazor Webassembly and find out how to call a javascript function from .NET code. My question is: Is it possible to read and write also a javascript variable from .NET. Here an example:

Javascript code loaded into page:

```
var Namespace1 = {
    prop1: 42, 
    func1: function () {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

from .NET I can call the function Namespace1.func1:

```
@code { 
    //private int prop1 { get; set; } = 1;
    private int ret1 { get; set; }

    override protected async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        // Error: The value 'window.Namespace1.prop1' is not a function.
        // ret1 = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<int>("Namespace1.prop1"); 
        ret1 = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<int>("Namespace1.func1");
        // return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to access also Namespace1.prop1 from .NET

Answer (score 5):

That's not possible currently as `IJsRuntime` only exposes methods that invoke javascript functions. [Details here on Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.ijsruntime?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

But you can write a js function and return a property:

```
var Namespace1 = {
    prop1: 42, 
    func1: function () {
        return prop1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Because it is for a project with a js lib (not my code) with a lot of properties it will not work. I will use angular for this.

Comment: You can create your own javascript that can have functions that can access the js properties that you want to access. So basically `blazor > your js > readonly js`